# Point Class Coordinates

Tags: java

I have an assignment explaining like this:

> Write a definition of a class named Point that might be used to store and manipulate the location of a point on the plane. The point is stored as two coordinates: x and y. You will need to declare and implement the following methods:
>
> 1. Two constructors:
>    a. no-argument constructor that sets the point coordinates to (0,0), and
>    b. a constructor that takes x and y coordinate of the point and sets member
>    variables.
> 2. Method set that sets the private data after an object of this class is created.
> 3. A method to move the point by an amount along the vertical and horizontal directions specified by the first and second arguments: move(double dx, double dy)
> 4. The method to rotate the point by 90 degrees clockwise around the origin.  Hint: when point is getting rotated 90 clockwise around the origin the following  changes happen to its coordinates:   xrotated = y;     yrotated = -x .
> 5. two accessor methods to retrieve the coordinates of the point.

It should be 2 different call. these items on second one (not main class)
I will call this on main class. (I do that).

This is my code but I dont understand what I should do next.

```
private double x;    
private double y;    


public Point(double initialX, double initialY) {
    x = initialX;
    y = initialY;
}


public Point() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}


public double getX() {
    return x;
}


public double getY() {
    return y;
}


public void move(double dx, double dy) {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;   
}
```

Comment: You're doing great ! Now you just have to implement `setX` , `setY`, and the `rotateBy90` methods. What problem are you having in doing that ?

Comment: I sent my code I think it is working but can you check if you are available

Answer (score 1):

You have almost everything, good job. For the rotate by 90 function, you're given a pretty good clue about what to do. Imagine you have a point (1,2), and you rotate it. you'll end up with (2,-1). if you rotate it again, you'll get (-1,-2). once more gives you (-2,1), and a fourth 90 degree rotation gives (1,2), which is what you started with. come up with a function that does this. It shouldn't be longer than 3 lines.

The setter functions (functions used to set, or change, the values) are simply functions you can use to set the values of the point. so, you'd have a function "setX(...) { ... }" and a function "setY(...) { ... }". These should be very straightforward.

Feel free to ask further questions if you're still confused.

Comment: so If I have imagine point : (2,1)  
first 90 clockwise  (-1,2)
sec 90 clockwise  (-2,-1)
third 90 clockwise (1,-2)
and last will be (2,1)  am I correct?

Comment: No, that's what happens when you rotate <b>counterclockwise</b>. The assignment asks that you rotate a point clockwise, and the example I gave   is what should happen.

Comment: I added this 2 method too
public double setX()
 {
  double xrot;
  return xrot = y;
  
 }
 
 public double setY()
 {
  double yrot;
  return yrot=-x;
 }

Comment: your function setX should take in a new value for x. imagine i wanted to set x to 5. then, all setX should do is make x = 5.

Comment: The functions setX and setY as defined in your comment aren't right. It's like you're confusing what rotate needs to do and what the setters need to do. Those functions shouldn't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: I am totally lost right now @Erik. can you write down here for me? just last part

Comment: I just edited my code under answer section. what about now? If it is still wrong I need correct one :(

Comment: We're going to discuss the "setX" function right now. Imagine I'm using your code for something. I have a point in my code. I decide I need to change the value of the x part of my point. So, i call the setX function on my point. First, what does your function need to know? Second, what does your function need to do?

Answer (score 1):

private double x;
    private double y;

```
public Point(double dx, double dy) {
    x = dx;
    y = dy;
}


public Point() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}


public double getX() {
    return x;
}


public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void SetX(double dx)
{
x = dx;
}


public void SetY(double dy)
{
y = dy;
}


public void move(double dx, double dy)
{
x = x + dx;
y = y + dy;
}

public double rotateX()
{
    double temp = x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;

return x;
}

public double rotateY()
{
    y=-y;

return y;
}
```

main page

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Point p = new Point();
    p.SetX(50);
    p.SetY(17);



    System.out.println("X and Y coordinates are :  \n("+p.getX()+","+p.getY()+")");
    System.out.println("after 90 degree clockwise rotate: ");
    System.out.println(p.rotateX()+","+p.rotateY());
```